# Elasticsearch query that requires all values in array to be present

Tags: elasticsearch

Heres a sample query:

```
{
    "query":{
        "constant_score":{
            "filter":{
                "terms":{
                    "genres_slugs":["simulator", "strategy", "adventure"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort":{
        "name.raw":{
            "order":"asc"
        }
    }
}
```

The value mapped to the `genres_slugs` property is just a simple array.

What i'm trying to do here is match all games that have all the values in the array: `["simulator","strategy","adventure"]`
As in, the resulting items MUST have all those values. What's returning instead are results that have only one value and not the others.

Been going at this for 6 hours now :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, if the resulting items MUST have all those values, use MUST param instead of FILTER.

```
{ "query": 
    { "constant_score" : 
          { "filter" : 
               { "bool" : 
                    { "must" : [ 
                           { "term" : 
                               {"genres_slugs":"simulator"}
                           },
                           { "term" : 
                               {"genres_slugs":"strategy"}
                           },
                           { "term" : 
                               {"genres_slugs":"adventure"}
                           }]
                    }
               }
          }
    }
}
```

This returns:

```
{
    "took": 54,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "try",
                "_type": "stackoverflowtry",
                "_id": "123",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "genres_slugs": [
                        "simulator",
                        "strategy",
                        "adventure"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "try",
                "_type": "stackoverflowtry",
                "_id": "126",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "genres_slugs": [
                        "simulator",
                        "strategy",
                        "adventure"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Doc:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-common-terms-query.html

Comment: I've tried  this already and it does the same thing:
`{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"terms":{"genres_slugs":["simulator","strategy","adventure"]}}}},"sort":{"name.raw":{"order":"asc"}}}`

Comment: try this:

{
    "query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                 "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                           { "term" : {"genres_slugs":["simulato‌​r","strategy","adven‌ture"]}}
}}}}

Comment: Doing that gives: `"[term] query does not support array of values"`. Turning that into `terms` fixes the error it but the search result is the same.

Comment: Ok... It's so strange. Maybe minimun_sould_match solve this. Look EDIT 2

Comment: Doing that returns nothing. :/

Comment: Ok, I try query and i found solution, look my new answer.

Comment: Thanks, I did a search with these terms: `['platform', 'adventure', 'indie', 'puzzle']`.   


But it's returning some games with only these genres `['platform', 'indie', 'adventure']`. (doesn't have the genre "puzzle"). Does this also happen to you or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You are doing something wrong, i'm my example i add:

"genres_slugs": [
                        "simulator",
                        "strategy"
                    ] 

and only find solutions with "genres_slugs": [
                        "simulator",
                        "strategy",
                        "adventure"
                    ]

Comment: I've changed my code to match your example but it's still not working for me, how are you mapping your properties?

Comment: Wait, scratch that. Your example is working perfectly fine now. The problem was that i was using PHP and when i turned your JSON object to PHP arrays i didn't put each `term` inside it's own array. Thanks again!

Comment: Hahahaha! I did not understand anything. I'm glad it works.